# Javascript hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('#countdown').countdown("2013/12/25 20:00", function(event) {`

I have that piece of code for my timer. But I want to have the current date and time plus one hour (rounded). It's kinda hard to explain but here is a example:

`It is 17:49 the date will be 2013/12/25 18:00`

`It is 20:22 the date will be 2013/12/25 21:00`

`It is 14:02 the date will be 2013/12/25 15:00`

Could someone help me with this? I'm really weak at javascript and I don't know where to start. I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: Given that this countdown is probably for New Year's you don't have much time. First look up how to get current time and how to add to it. Then we can guide you with some more logic. You need to show that you have tried something for people to answer here.

Comment: So 23:01 2013/12/31 => 2014/01/01 00:00 ?

Comment: The countdown is not made for Ney Year, it's for a project I'm working on. With my logic; I should get the current time -> round the hours (?) -> add one hour. Getting the time and adding a hour wouldn't be a problem but I don't know any javascript function how to "round" the hour. For example 21:12 -> 22:00.

Comment: @Megawac Yes, that's a example that fits. 14:46 2014/02/10 => 2014/02/10 15:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a date object with the next hour

```
function nextHour(date) {

    date.setHours(date.getHours()+1);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    return date;
}
var date=new Date();
var nextDate=nextHour(new Date());
alert("it is "+date+", and it will be "+nextDate);
```

Obviously, you'll have to format the date a bit, but that shouldn't be that hard